# Flow not emitting any value

Tags: android, android-room

I have a sql query in Room which checks whether table is empty or not and returns Flow. It emits for the first time but not after inserting in table

Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM weather_location)")
    fun checkIfTableEmpty(): Flow<Boolean>
```

Flow:

```
class WeatherLocationsEmptyUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val locationRepository: LocationRepository
) {
    operator fun invoke(): Flow<TableState> {
        return locationRepository.checkIfTableEmpty().map { isNotEmpty ->
            if(isNotEmpty) {
                TableState.NotEmpty
            } else {
                TableState.Empty
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share where you collected it? (flow)

Comment: @ArdaKazancı i was checking with log statements in the map block.

Comment: use .collect @Ans T